# User Profiles in a 3 tiered CouchDB and Laravel app

Tags: nosql, couchdb, laravel, 3-tier, cloudant

I'm developing a web application in Laravel 4 that has multiple users, each one with a profile. These profiles may (or may not) have different variables, such as dates, etc. I've looked at some RDBMS solutions for this problem including `EAV` design, but this method is really expensive in terms of both performance and code, so I discarded it.

The other option was  tocreate a huge table with many columns, but I also discarded it since it is pretty useless to have a user with 30 null fields.

So I was thinking about using NoSQL and I ended up with CouchDB for the scalability and master-master replication. I looked into some DBaaS and found Cloudant quite interesting. The real question is: Is it really the option for my case (having users with a profile with different variables for each user)? Or is it doable with a RDBMS (MySQL)? Also, How can I use CouchDB with Laravel in a 3 tiered app? I don't want the user to have access to neither of the database's features, I really think that using CouchDB on the server side is the best option so far, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having non-homogenous data like you is the typical case where document-oriented databases like CouchDB or MongoDB are better than relational databases.

While CouchDB can be configured to be public-facing and being directly accessible by the clients (there are even proof-of-concepts of whole web applications served solely by CouchDB), this is quite uncommon in practice. The usual scenario is to use CouchDB as a hidden backend service which is used by a webserver running some kind of server-sided web technology like PHP, JSP, ASP or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! can you provide me with some information about using it in the 2-tier? I'v found Doctrine's ODM but i'm not quite sure about its benefits.

Comment: @DilipRamirez That's a new question.